# Segmentation faults in x86 NASM program

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, nasm

I have an assignment where I must create a text file, such as:

```
4
5 3 6 7
8 2 3 1
8 9 6 3
4 2 1 9
```

where '4' defines number of rows/columns and write a program in NASM that finds the sum of the diagonal numbers, so in this example:

```
5 + 2 + 6 + 3
```

and obviously it would return the sum, 22.

I'm pretty sure I have it all set up to work right. I take input of the file, and use the first number in the file to define the dimensions of the file. So if the first number is 4, the dimension of the file is 4^2 + 1 (the 1 is to account for the first number). n^2 + 1 is also the exit condition for the loop that does the next paragraph:

At this point I use fscanf() to go through the file one by one and add it to an array. After this all I need to do is get each n+1 element of the array (where n = 4 in this case) until the end of the array is reached and add them all together.

That last paragraph all happens in '.diagonals' label towards the bottom, and everything up until that point works. If you were to comment it out the program would to back to working fine.

Can someone tell what's going on there that's causing issues?

Code (there's a lot of comments so it might be easier to follow if you pasted it in your own editor):

```
extern  fopen
extern  fclose
extern  fscanf
extern  printf

global  main

SEGMENT .data
n:                      DD      0
i:                      DD      0
x:                      DD      0                       ; variable for first digit of the file, which determines the number of rows/columns in the file
loopCounter: DD 0                       ; will be set to (n-1) where n is the first number in the file
sum1:           DD      0
sum2:           DD      0
format:         DD      "%d",0
formatInt:      DD      "%d ",0
readmode:       DD      "r", 0
filename:       DD      "hw5_2.dat", 0

SEGMENT .text
main:

        push    readmode                ; push "r"
        push    filename                ; filehandle
        call    fopen                   ; open file, returns pointer to file in eax
        add             esp, 8                  ; balance stack

        xor             esi, esi                ; clear esi
        xor             ecx, ecx                ; clear ecx
        mov             ebx, eax                ; move pointer to file to ebx
        jmp             .fileCycle

.firstLoop:                                     ; this is the first time the loop has run so it must determine the first value to use for the number of rows/columns

        xor             eax, eax                ; clear eax, just in case
        mov             eax, edi                ; move first number from file into eax

        mov             [loopCounter], eax      ; loopCounter = 4
        sub             [loopCounter], dword 1
        ;mov            [x], edi                ; move it also into [x], may need it later
        mul             eax                             ; eax = eax*eax
        mov             edx, eax                ; move result to edx

        mov             [x], eax                ; also move result to [x]
        add             [x], dword 4    ; add 4 to [x], this will become the offset later when adding the diagonals together


        inc             eax                             ; number of elements is n^2 + 1, so eax must be incremented
        inc             ecx                             ; increment loop counter, as this method runs before it can happen in the loop
        jmp             .fileCycle              ; resume loop, this method will not run again

.fileCycle:                                     ; this method cycles through the file and adds all the elements one by one into the esi register

        cmp             ecx, eax                ; end of file?
        ;je             .finished              
        je              .diagonals              ; YES - time to find diagonals

        push    eax
        push    ebx
        push    ecx
        push    edx

        push    n                               ; store scanned value in n
        push    format                  ; store as int
        push    ebx                             ; get input from file pointed to by eax
        call    fscanf
        add             esp, 12                 ; balance stack

        mov             edi, [n]                ; move value at n into edi
        mov             [esi+i], edi    ; store values in file as an array of ints located at esi

.printElement:

        push    dword [esi+i]   ; pass current element of array by value
        push    formatInt               ; pass format argument
        call    printf                  ; print current element
        add             esp, 8                  ; balance stack

        pop             edx
        pop             ecx
        pop             ebx
        pop             eax

        add             [i], dword 4    ; increment array index
        cmp             ecx, dword 0    ; is this the first time going through the loop?
        je              .firstLoop              ; YES - firstLoop method must be run

        inc             ecx                             ; inc loop counter     
        jmp             .fileCycle              ; NO - keep looping

.diagonals:                                     ; calculate the first diagonal sum
        xor             eax, eax                ; clear certain registers to be reused
        xor             ecx, ecx
        xor             edi, edi

        mov             ecx, dword 4    ; start the counter at 4 so it grabs the 2nd number of the array first
.L1:
        cmp             edi, [loopCounter]      ; compare edi (local loop counter) to loopCounter (the number of diagonals to add)
        je              .finished                       ; counters are equal - program finished

        mov             eax, [esi+ecx]  ; move next diagonal element into eax
        add             [sum1], eax             ; add it to the sum

        add             ecx, [x]                ; ecx += 20, 20 in this case is the dword offset to get the next diagonal
        inc             edi                             ; inc loop counter     


.finished:

        push    ebx
        call    fclose                  ; close the file
        add             esp, 4

        ret
```

Comment: I don't use nasm, so syntax might be correct; but when you push n, are you sure this pushes &n (as it should), and not value in n?

Comment: I think so. Before I added the 'diagonals' label all the program did was output the array after values had been parsed to it from the file. But it worked fine then so I think it should be something after that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You zero `esi` and never change it. `mov eax, [esi+ecx]` will thus access invalid memory.

The code is suspicious in other ways: how is `mov [esi+i], edi` reasonable considering that `i` is a single dword?

Comment: In the very beginning of my program I zero esi, but afterwards it contains the array of numbers parsed from the file. I use esi in '.printElement' and it works fine there

Comment: Also, i gets 4 added to it through each iteration of the loop, it's just an offset to move edi to the next element of the array

Comment: `esi` is not written to in this program, other than being zeroed. If there is other code, then please say so. As for `i`: it is a label, and `[esi+i]` will use the address of the label and not the value stored there.

Comment: Oh now I see it. You're totally right, I'm going to have to completely restructure how '.diagonals' works. Thanks for your help.